# How do I install update the BIOS of my Acer Aspire 4820TG laptop?

Tags: laptop, acer, bios, firmware, aspire

The BIOS update for the Acer Aspire 4820TG is distributed as a zip file, containing a Windows executable and a DOS executable.

How do I get this installed under Ubuntu without resorting to installing Windows?

The files I intend to install are located on this[page](http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?modelId=2076).

Comment: a windows driver on linux? , nope..never and what does this firmware do? what is suppose to update?

Comment: I've just clarified the question. I want to update the BIOS of the laptop from v1.15 to v1.25.

Comment: In the end, I took the easy way out of booting into Windows and running the firmware update. I just wasn't confident enough in the supplied FreeDOS method and didn't want to risk bricking my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to update the BIOS without installing windows.

[UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318789) has an excellent tutorial which you should consult.

Since it looks like Acer does not have a linux friendly way of updating the BIOS, then use the FreeDOS method described in the tutorial together with the DOS BIOS exe that Acer supply.

Comment: Yes, you either need to use FreeDOS to run their DOS flash utility, or check and see if the bios has a built in utility to flash itself.  Many motherboards these days can do that if you point them to the file on a cd or usb flash stick.